# Why does this import() promise get rejected while require() works fine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, promise, require

My code is as follows:

```
'use strict';

import('mysql').then(result => console.log('then'))
    .catch(error => console.log('catch'));

console.log(require('mysql'));
```

When I run `node thisScript.js`, the console output is this:

```
{
  createConnection: [Function: createConnection],
  createPool: [Function: createPool],
  createPoolCluster: [Function: createPoolCluster],
  createQuery: [Function: createQuery],
  escape: [Function: escape],
  escapeId: [Function: escapeId],
  format: [Function: format],
  raw: [Function: raw]
}
catch
```

If I remove the line with `require('mysql')`, the console output is just `catch`.

Comment: Your code says
```import('mysql')```
It should be
```require('mysql')```

Comment: @MestreSan `import('module')` is a thing as far as I can tell. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: But you've got to check what version of NodeJS you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: @MestreSan Aha. It's 12.16.3.